# Programmatically check for compilation errors java file

Tags: java

I want to programmatically check if a java class has compilation errors. 
Can you please let me know how it can be done?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [JavaCompiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to compile the class and it will let you know if there are some compile errors.

Contrived example (using a string as an input, but you can read a file instead):

```
String className = "somepackage.YourClass";
String body = "package somepackage;   "
                + "public class YourClass {         "
                + "}                              ";
compile(className, body, TEMP_PATH); //TEMP_PATH: Where the .class file is saved
```

where compile could look like this:

```
private static void compile(String className, String body, Path path) throws Exception {
    List<JavaSourceFromString> sourceCode = Arrays.asList(new JavaSourceFromString(className, body));

    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(path.toFile()));
    boolean ok = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, sourceCode).call();

    System.out.println("compilation ok = " + ok);
}
```

Comment: +1 And also find a sample Example. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompileaJavafilewithJavaCompiler.htm)